# TOPIC_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED, val=29, str="Broker: Topic authorization failed error from MSK

Tags: apache-kafka, aws-msk

Our team has created a MSK cluster with SASL_SSL as security protocol.
When we try to publish data from our python client, getting below error -

Failed to deliver message: <cimpl.Message object at 0x000001E88C23A040>: KafkaError{code=TOPIC_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED,val=29,str="Broker: Topic authorization failed"}

Code -

```
from confluent_kafka import Producer
import socket

def acked(err, msg):
    if err is not None:
        print("Failed to deliver message: %s: %s" % (str(msg), str(err)))
    else:
        print("Message produced: %s" % (str(msg)))

def produce():
    print("producer.....")
    conf = {'bootstrap.servers': 'b-1-public.mskqapoc01.*****a.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9196,b-2-public.mskqapoc01.*********.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9196',
            'security.protocol': 'SASL_SSL',
            'sasl.mechanism': 'SCRAM-SHA-512',
            'sasl.username': 'user',
            'sasl.password': 'password',
            'client.id': socket.gethostname()}
    
    producer = Producer(conf)
    producer.produce("Kafkapasstopic", key="0", value="first message from mh", callback=acked)

    # Wait up to 1 second for events. Callbacks will be invoked during
    # this method call if the message is acknowledged.
    producer.poll(1)
    producer.flush()

produce()
```

Any idea what could the reason? is it an issue from client or something missing while creating MSK cluster?

Below is security config of msk cluster :
[image]

Thanks
Mahendra

Comment: Have you associated your secrets (username and password) with the MSK cluster using the api here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/kafka/batch-associate-scram-secret.html ?

Answer (score 0):

MHegde,

It doesn't seem like your code is a problem.

Since you [enabled public access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/public-access.html) to the cluster, you had to change a property: `allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=false`.

Please make sure you allow the user you are using in your code to access your topic. You will need to use kafka-acls command tool:

```
kafka/bin/kafka-acls.sh --bootstrap-server b-1-public.mskqapoc01.*****a.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9196 \
  --command-config kafka/config/sasl-scram-config.conf \
  --add \
  --allow-principal User:YOUR_ACTUAL_USERNAME \
  --operation read \
  --operation write \
  --topic Kafkapasstopic
```

Make sure your file `kafka/config/sasl-scram-config.conf` has the following definition:

```
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-512
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="<username>" password="<password>";
```