Create Topic Authorization Problem on Amazon MSK (Public Kafka)
We have a Kafka server running on Amazon AWS. This is a public server with SASL/SCRAM enabled. We can successfully authenticate but when we try to create a new topic, we get an authorization error.
This is the command we use for creating a topic:
./kafka-topics --create --replication-factor 2 --partitions 1 --topic TestTopic --bootstrap-server my-servers --command-config config.properties

config.properties file contains SASL authentication information:
sasl.mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-512
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required \
    username="user" \
    password="pass";

This is the error message:
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException: Authorization failed.

We are new to public Kafka so can't figure out how to solve this. Any help is appreciated.
Edit:
I think the error occurs due to ACLs. I tried the following two commands but I'm getting the same error for both:
1)
./kafka-acls --bootstrap-server my_servers \
  --command-config config.properties \
  --add \
  --allow-principal User:my_user \
  --operation read \
  --operation write \
  --topic Kafkapasstopic

Error:
Adding ACLs for resource `ResourcePattern(resourceType=TOPIC, name=Kafkapasstopic, patternType=LITERAL)`:
    (principal=User:my_user, host=*, operation=WRITE, permissionType=ALLOW)
    (principal=User:my_user, host=*, operation=READ, permissionType=ALLOW)

Error while executing ACL command: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ClusterAuthorizationException: Request Request(***), listenerName=ListenerName(CLIENT_SASL_SCRAM_PUBLIC), securityProtocol=SASL_SSL, buffer=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=108 lim=108 cap=108], envelope=None) is not authorized.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ClusterAuthorizationException: Request Request(***), listenerName=ListenerName(CLIENT_SASL_SCRAM_PUBLIC), securityProtocol=SASL_SSL, buffer=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=108 lim=108 cap=108], envelope=None) is not authorized.
    
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ClusterAuthorizationException: Request Request(***), listenerName=ListenerName(CLIENT_SASL_SCRAM_PUBLIC), securityProtocol=SASL_SSL, buffer=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=108 lim=108 cap=108], envelope=None) is not authorized.


./kafka-acls --bootstrap-server my_servers --add --allow-principal User:my_user --operation Create --operation Alter --cluster --command-config config.properties

Error:
Adding ACLs for resource `ResourcePattern(resourceType=CLUSTER, name=kafka-cluster, patternType=LITERAL)`:
        (principal=User:my_user, host=*, operation=CREATE, permissionType=ALLOW)
        (principal=User:my_user, host=*, operation=ALTER, permissionType=ALLOW)
    
Error while executing ACL command: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ClusterAuthorizationException: Request Request(Session(User:kafka,/***), listenerName=ListenerName(CLIENT_SASL_SCRAM_PUBLIC), securityProtocol=SASL_SSL, buffer=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=104 lim=104 cap=104], envelope=None) is not authorized.
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ClusterAuthorizationException: Request Request(***), listenerName=ListenerName(CLIENT_SASL_SCRAM_PUBLIC), securityProtocol=SASL_SSL, buffer=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=104 lim=104 cap=104], envelope=None) is not authorized.
   kafka.admin.AclCommand$AdminClientService.addAcls(AclCommand.scala:111)
        at kafka.admin.AclCommand$.main(AclCommand.scala:73)
        at kafka.admin.AclCommand.main(AclCommand.scala)
    Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ClusterAuthorizationException: Request Request(***), listenerName=ListenerName(CLIENT_SASL_SCRAM_PUBLIC), securityProtocol=SASL_SSL, buffer=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=104 lim=104 cap=104], envelope=None) is not authorized.

Edit 2:
@EdbE suggested to use ACL with zookeeper. But I still get an error:
Command:
./kafka-acls \
    --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=zookeeper-connection-string \
    --add --allow-principal User:my_user \
    --operation Create
    --operation Alter \
    --cluster \
    --command-config config.properties

Error:

Warning: support for ACL configuration directly through the authorizer
is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use
--bootstrap-server instead to set ACLs through the admin client. You must provide at least one resource: --topic  or --cluster or
--group  or --delegation-token 


I think it's a dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78146386/topic-authorization-failed-val-29-str-broker-topic-authorization-failed-erro/78209365#78209365 can you confirm?

@EdbE I believe my problem is also due to ACLs but I'm also having problem with running ACL commands. I updated my post, can you check?

it doesn't look like an error, it looks like a warning

Current state of the cluster:

public access enabled
SASL-SCRAM is used for authorization

This means:

allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=false

Since you did not define any user authorization prior to disabling no-acl access, you won't be able to access or change on this cluster anything as long as authorizer is used.
To overcome this, you can use ACL command with zookeeper instead of bootstrap:
kafka/bin/kafka-acls.sh \
    --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=$ZK \
    --add --allow-principal User:my_user \
    --operation Create 
    --operation Alter \
    --cluster \
    --command-config config.properties

Note,
Zookeeper nodes do not require authentication, hence need to be protected using Security Groups. Allow access only from IP/SG used by an admin client host.

Can you please check the update on the post? I'm having trouble running your command.

Excellent. Dozens of other answers in similar questions didn't help: "Since you did not define any user authorization prior to disabling no-acl access, you won't be able to access or change on this cluster anything as long as authorizer is used"
